# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException while using ExecutorService

Tags: java, future, executorservice

I am working on some project in which I am using Observer design Pattern.
Subject class is :

```
public class Subject {
    private List<Observer> observers = new ArrayList<Observer>();
    private int state;
    public void setState(int state) {
          this.state = state;
          notifyAllObservers();
    }
    public void attach(Observer observer){
          observers.add(observer);      
    }
    public void notifyAllObservers(){
          for (Observer observer : observers) {
             observer.update();
           }
   }
   public void deattach(Observer observer) {
         observers.remove(observer);
   }
}
```

Observer Interface is:

```
public abstract class Observer implements Runnable{
    protected Subject subject;
    public abstract void update();
    public abstract void process();
}
```

One of the Observer Named as HexObserver is:

```
public class HexaObserver extends Observer {

    private ExecutorService threadpool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    public HexaObserver(Subject subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
        this.subject.attach(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void update() {
        System.out.println("Hex String: "
                + Integer.toHexString(subject.getState()));
        Future future = threadpool.submit(new HexaObserver(subject));

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("In run :D :D :D");

    }

    @Override
        public void process() {
            // TODO 
        }
}
```

Class to test this is:

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Subject subject = new Subject();
        HexaObserver hob = new HexaObserver(subject);
        System.out.println("First state change: 15");
        subject.setState(15);
    }
}
```

When I tried to run this this is giving some Error:

```
First state change: 15
Hex String: f
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:859)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:831)
    at Observer.Subject.notifyAllObservers(Subject.java:23)
    at Observer.Subject.setState(Subject.java:15)
    at Observer.Demo.main(Demo.java:12)
In run :D :D :D
```

I didn't get why I am getting this error as `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown out when we try to modify some Object concurrently when it is not permissible.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: It looks like this is because your HexaObserver is adding an element to the array list while the notification loop is happening. Try changing `ArrayList` to a concurrent implementation such as a `CopyOnWriteArrayList`

Comment: BretC seems to be right. I dont understand why in update() a new HexaObserver is added (including implicit attach in Constructor). Probably `submit(this)` was intended? Or submit a new immutable and threadsafe Object without implicit attach.

Comment: @Bret C : yaa [CopyOnWriterArrayList] will work but It is so costly. By the way method suggested by Markus Kull is also good. I really intended this only.

Answer (score 1):

Two things are happening at the same time: you are iterating over `observers` and adding an element to `observers`. That causes your `ConcurrentModificationException`

In general there are at least three things you can do:

- use a synchronized collection
- thread-safely copy the collection and iterate on a copy
- manually synchronize all access to `observers` with `synchronized` block:

```
public void attach(Observer observer){
      synchronized(observers){ 
          observers.add(observer);      
      }
}
public void notifyAllObservers(){
      synchronized(observers){ 
          for (Observer observer : observers) {
             observer.update();
          }
      }
}
public void deattach(Observer observer) {
      synchronized(observers){ 
           observers.remove(observer);
      }
}
```

- you can also mark whole methods as `synchronized`, but then they will synchronize on an instance of `Subject` and not on the collection instance.

However, in your case the problem is connected to what your `update()` does.
Are you sure your `HexaObserver`'s `update` should create a new `HexaObserver`? Because you are adding a new instance of the same class to a collection which already contains that instance.

Comment: Yeah, it's because of the `new HexaObserver` I mention in my answer. You are iterating and modifying the same collection from the same thread.

Answer (score 0):

`ConcurrentModificationException` is usually the sign that you used an `Iterator` on a `Collection` and that while iterating, you also modified the underlying `Collection` (remember that foreach-expression are actually a shortcut for using `Iterator`). The only way to solve this, is to iterate on a copy of the original collection. If you are in a multi-threaded environment, you also need to ensure that the copy of the collection is done in a thread-safe way.

So you could for example have:

```
public class Subject {
    private List<Observer> observers = new Vector<Observer>();
    private int state;
    public void setState(int state) {
          this.state = state;
          notifyAllObservers();
    }
    public void attach(Observer observer){
          observers.add(observer);      
    }
    public void notifyAllObservers(){
          for (Observer observer : ((List<Observer)observers.clone())) {
             observer.update();
           }
   }
   public void deattach(Observer observer) {
         observers.remove(observer);
   }
}
```